# How to generate a fake HTTP request object for unit test in Python?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, httprequest

In a Python Django project, we want a unit test to feed a HTTP POST request into the function under test. The `cURL` sample command below shows our test settings.

The `cURL` approach starts from the web server's endpoint and triggers the entire logic path, but we want the unit test to focus on a specific function taking in the `request` argument. And, we got hint from [this post](https://gist.github.com/majgis/4164503) with the below sample Python source code to fake a HTTP request for testing.

##### Our Question:

See the `-d` argument of the `cURL` command, we wonder how to feed the request body in the faked object.

##### Technical Details:

- **The `cURL` command:**

```bash
curl http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/transaction/ --insecure \
    --verbose \
    -d '<env:Envelope ... >
  <env:Header>
    ...
  </env:Header>
  <env:Body>
    ...
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
'
```

- **The Python sample source code for faking a HTTP request:**

```py
from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIRequest
from io import StringIO
from django.contrib.auth.models import AnonymousUser

def GetFakeRequest(path='/', user=None):
    """ Construct a fake request(WSGIRequest) object"""
    req = WSGIRequest({
        'REQUEST_METHOD': 'GET',
        'PATH_INFO': path,
        'wsgi.input': StringIO()})

    req.user = AnonymousUser() if user is None else user
    return req
```

Comment: You want to use the return for `GetFakeRequest` as a parameter to the function is it!?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an alternative is to build the `request` object using [`RequestFactory`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/testing/advanced/#the-request-factory). And call the the function using such as param. Something like:

tests.py

```py
from django.test import TestCase, RequestFactory
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

from myapp.views import my_function


class TestHTTPRequest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        self.data = "<env:Envelope ... > \
                        <env:Header> \
                            ... \
                        </env:Header> \
                        <env:Body> \
                            ... \
                        </env:Body> \
                    </env:Envelope>"
        self.factory = RequestFactory()
        self.user = get_user_model().objects.create_user(
            username="john", email="john_doe@test.com", password="top_secret"
        )

    def test_some_function(self):
        request = self.factory.get("some/url/", data={'data': self.data})
        request.user = self.user

        response = my_function(request)

        self.assertEqual(response, "Some way to confirm success")
```

views.py

```
def my_function(request):
    data = request.GET.get('data')
    # print(f'The data: \n {data}')
    
    # print(request.user.email)

    return "Some way to confirm success"
```

I placed it inside views, but of course it can be anywhere you want.